# Question marks '???' before doctype in HTML UTF-8 email, the rest of the document is fine

Tags: html, character-encoding

Im aware there are other posts on character encoding however this one appears to only occur before the doctype.

My original source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
```

But it comes through in an email as (note the question marks at the start):

```
???<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
```

This seems strange as there are no characters or whitespace before the doctype. I don't really get 'what' can't be rendered. Also, the file was originally saved in visual studio using the following settings:

[image: Visual Studio Encoding Type]

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually characters before the doctype. As you have saved the file as UTF-8 with signature, it contains a BOM ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) at the beginning of the file.

Save it as UTF-8 without signature, and the characters will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a **< / html > ** tag ending the whole code. Try that. If it still isn't working,  I suggest you use notepad++ instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: This is just the top few lines of the document, but I'll try in notepad++